# Dragonfly Identification

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I have been clearing brush by a lake in northwest Missouri and seen a lot of dragonflies. It's hard to get decent pictures because my phone camera sucks and they fly away before I get close. But here is one I managed to get:
[image]

I got one other picture of another species, but it's much lower quality.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is a blue dasher ([*Pachydiplax longipennis*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_dasher)).

Sorry, I couldn't identify the second one but it is more probably the same.

[image]

Comment: Did you want to edit this further? I was reluctant to accept it right away, but I think you're correct on the first one. The second one is probably too blurry to tell much.

Comment: @user137: Thanks. I completely forgot about this one. I still think they both are the same. source:  http://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.asp?identification=Blue-Dasher

Answer (score 4):

The overall body shape of the second dragonfly looks like a [Libellula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libellula) (Skimmer), due to its broad flat abdomen. It also seems to have distinct bands on all four wings, dark patches where the wings connect and a light blue abdomen, which would indicate e.g. a male [*Plathemis/Libellula lydia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_whitetail) (Common whitetail). The picture is blurry though, and there might be other similar species that it can be mistaken for (the wiki page mentions a couple of similar species).

[image]
(picture from wikipedia)

Comment: It looks right to me. I probably should have split this into 2 questions so I could have two answers.

Comment: @user137 Well, its difficult to know in advance whether you've seen one or two species.